# Java Web Start getting two Windows when only need one

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, java-web-start

Hello I am migrating my Java applet to Java Web Start as Firefox disabled Java NPAPI support.

I am using JNLP to open to load the applet. Inside the applet I am extending Applet Class to the main class.

When we open the applet a File Chooser is opened where we have to select a folder and save its path.

But when we launch web start application I get 2 windows one window is empty and another window of File Chooser which I opened using JFileChooser.showSaveDialog.

I want the File Chooser to open in the main window started by web start and not in a new window. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: *"Please tell me how to do it."* There's really not enough information here to help you achieve the requirement. What's the content of the JNLP? That's the code? For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: I think the FileChooser might always be a window of its own. Never seen a file chooser that's inside another window, it always pops up separately. So your question would be, how to make an applet without a main window.

Comment: @StefanHegny *"I think the FileChooser might always be a window of its own."* Yes, both the AWT `FileDialog` and Swing `JFileChooser` are based in a dialog, which is a top level container that cannot be embedded in another TLC. If that's what the OP means, perhaps they should abandon the applet completely and use the HTML 5 [`input` of type `file`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120320/input.file.html). The days of applets are numbered in any case. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) ..

Comment: .. and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: Hey guys, i finally found out a way to get the dialog window in the parent container. The only thing i had to do was to avoid this code: int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(aComponent);